# Parsing filesystem locations into usable file:// urls in chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I'm saving files to the user's hard drive in my chrome extension, and I need to have a way to open up the file in the chrome browser programatically. I can accomplish using the chrome tabs API to create a tab and sets its url. The problem is the filesystem address of the file.

Chrome switches special characters in the file name to other expressions, for example spaces become %20.

To counteract this problem, I want to parse the file names before I save them, removing the characters that would cause these url corruptions.

I can't figure out the RegEx to correctly parse the file name.

There are two things that could help me:

1. A list of all the special characters that cause these corruptions in the url when you open it in Chrome.
2. Or even better, an instant solution from help with a RegEx that I can use with javascript's [replace method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace every "/" with a "\", and every other character that isn't a letter or a number (or the "\" that I just added) with a "_"

Edit:

I wont be able to open the file in the chrome tab if I don't take into account these changes to the string. For example, the below code won't work.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'file:///home/user/1057_AngularJS: Developer Guide: Directives.mhtml'}, function(tab) {
  });
});
```

I'd need to do:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'file:///home/user/1057%5CAngularJS:%20Developer%20Guide:%20Directives.mhtml'}, function(tab) {
  });
});`
```

I wanted to replace the /s with \s just so that the filesystem url is as similar to a webpage url as possible, but if that causes problems I can forgo that.

Comment: Chrome is properly encoding the file name for use in a URL.  What are you trying to do?  And, why would you want to replace `/` with `\ ` ?  Only Windows uses `\ `, and Windows will typically tolerate paths with `/`.

Comment: It is not url corruption, it is `url encoding`. Without it some strange stuff may occur. Just use some `url_decode` method

Comment: good point, uri encoding, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent, my file name to give the properly escaped filesystem path would solve my problem too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> an instant solution from help with a RegEx that I can use with
>   javascript's replace method to replace every "/" with a "\", and every
>   other character that isn't a letter or a number (or the "\" that I
>   just added) with a "_"

Here you are:

```
'Hello/你 好/1337'.replace(/\//g, '\\').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\\]/g, '_');
```

Output:

```
'Hello\___\1337'
```

Comment: That replaces the /'s with _'s instead of \'s. Is inserting the \'s possible?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]/g, '_')`, or not replacing the /'s with \'s because \'s are encoded as special characters as well. I also wanted to keep the periods in the file name. To see a full list of characters that are encoded, go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).